# Pandas - merge column value with the same ID into a list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merger all depart_time value with the same location into a list

```
location    depart_time
022HK   1160
022HK   680
022HK   783.51667
022HK   1268.51667
```

desired ouput:

```
location  depart_time
022HK    [680, 783.51667, 1160 1268.51667]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

`df.groupby('location')['depart_time'].apply(list)`